# ContextMenu.PlacementTarget is not getting set, no idea why

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, binding

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="_ItemTemplateA">
  <Grid Tag="{Binding Path=DataContext.Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTemplateB}" Grid.Row="0" />
    <ContentControl Name="uiContentPresenter" Content="{Binding ContentView}" Grid.Row="1" Height="0" />
    <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding IsContentDisplayed}" DataContextChanged="IsDisplayed_Changed" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Text" 
              Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
      </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The above data template is applied to an ItemsControl.  The issue is that for the ContextMenu that is specified for the Grid, the PlacementTarget property is never actually getting set to anything so I cannot get to the Tag property of the Grid which is necessary for passing the Command that should execute on the parent UserControl down to the context menu.  I've based this approach off of similar examples such as this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0244fbb0-fd5f-4a03-bd7b-978d7cbe1be3/

I've not been able to identify any other good way to pass this command down.  This is setup this way because we are using an MVVM approach so the command we have to execute lives in the View Model of the user control this template is applied in.  I've tried explicitly setting the PlacementTarget in a few different ways but it still always shows up as not set.

Comment: I am too facing the same issue...Any workarounds.

Comment: I am experiencing this exact issue, as well. For me, it's with a `ListView`. I put a breakpoint in my `UserControl`'s `Loaded` event handler and inspected the `<ListView.ContextMenu>`'s `PlacementTarget` property... `null`. :(

Comment: I too am facing the issue of the PlacementTarget being null when my ContextMenu is opened causing no possible link back to the information in the window/user control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realise that this is old and answered, but it doesn't seem properly answered. I came across a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621550/how-to-get-the-placementtarget-on-wpf-context-menu-when-item-click-using-mvvm-pa/15306413#15306413) and left a full answer. You might like to take a look as you can get it working with just a few adjustments to your code.

First, name your view `UserControl`... I generally name all of mine `This` for simplicity. Then remembering that our view model is bound to the `DataContext` of the `UserControl`, we can bind to the view model using `{Binding DataContext, ElementName=This}`.

So now we can bind to the view model, we have to connect that with the `ContextMenu.DataContext`. I use the `Tag` property of the object with the `ContextMenu` (the `PlacementTarget`) as that connection, in this example, a `Grid`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="YourTemplate" DataType="{x:Type DataTypes:YourDataType}">
    <Grid ContextMenu="{StaticResource Menu}" Tag="{Binding DataContext, 
        ElementName=This}">
        ...
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

We can then access the view model properties and commands in the `ContextMenu` by binding the `ContextMenu.DataContext` property to the `PlacementTarget.Tag` property (of the `Grid` in our example):

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="Menu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource=
    {RelativeSource Self}}">
    <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteFile}" CommandParameter=
        "{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
        AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" CommandTarget="{Binding PlacementTarget, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

Note the binding on the `MenuItem.CommandTarget` property. Setting this ensures that the target element on which the specified command is raised is the `PlacementTarget`, or the `Grid` in this case.

Also note the `CommandParameter` binding. This binds to the `DataContext` of the `PlacementTarget`, or the `Grid` in this case. The `DataContext` of the `Grid` will be inherited from the `DataTemplate` and so your data item is now bound to the `object` parameter in your `Command` if you're using some implementation of the `ICommand` interface:

```
public bool CanExecuteDeleteFileCommand(object parameter)
{
    return ((YourDataType)parameter).IsInvalid;
}

public void ExecuteDeleteFileCommand(object parameter)
{
    Delete((YourDataType)parameter);
}
```

Or if you are using some kind of `RelayCommand` delegates directly in your view model:

```
public ICommand Remove
{
    get 
    {
        return new ActionCommand(execute => Delete((YourDataType)execute), 
            canExecute => return ((YourDataType)canExecute).IsInvalid); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that the PlacementTarget is not being set. From the code example in the original post, you can see that the issue is NOT using the PlacementTarget, but the fact that the framework is for some reason not setting it!

Answer (score 3):

We have the same problem, but it works randomly. A contextmenu inside the controltemplate in a style for a listbox. We have tried to move the contextmenu to different levels inside the template but the same error occurs.

We think it might be connected to the refreshing of our ICollectionView that is the itemssource of the ListBox.

It seems that when the view refreshes the relative source binding inside the contextmenu is being evaluated before the PlacementTarget is being set.

It feels like a bug in either collectionviewsource or the ContextMenu of WPF...

Comment: did you came up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working standalone XAML-only example based on your test case: a `ContextMenu` that retrieves a `Command` from the `DataContext` of its `PlacementTarget` using a `Tag`.  You can reintroduce portions of your code until it stops working to try to find where the problem is:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <PointCollection x:Key="sampleData">
            <Point X="10" Y="20"/>
            <Point X="30" Y="40"/>
        </PointCollection>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="_ItemTemplateA">
            <Grid Tag="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DockPanel}}}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding X}"/>
                <Grid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Grid.ContextMenu>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DockPanel DataContext="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Open}">
        <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource _ItemTemplateA}" ItemsSource="{StaticResource sampleData}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5b6e224d-5fd6-4b15-88bf-e103d67b4ed6/placementtarget-of-a-context-menu-is-always-null?forum=wpf),

> ContextMenu.PlacementTarget is filled up from ContextMenuService.PlacementTarget when you do right click with mouse on button.

It means ContextMenu.PlacementTarget is filled up when the menu is shown up. You can check that by snoop.

EDIT 1
This code works fine.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridRowBaseStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext}"/>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuStyle}" 
                             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}">
                    <MenuItem Header="Enable" Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.(viewModels:PrinterListPageViewModel.EnableCommand), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's an old question but an effective solution to this bug is to create a `class` that inherits from `ContextMenu`, then add a new `DependencyProperty` of type `PlacementMode` with a name for example MenuPlacement, after that override `OnOpened` void of the new menu class, finally assign the value of MenuPlacement property to the original Placement property.