# How to get the PlacementTarget on WPF Context menu when item click using MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, contextmenu

How to get the PlacementTarget of selected ContextMenu when using MVVM pattern ?

I can get PlacementTarget like this when using MenuItem click event. But how it do it MVVM ?

```
   public void changeGaugeColor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem tempMenuItem = (MenuItem)sender;

        MenuItem mi = (MenuItem)sender;
        bd = (BidirectionalDial)cm.PlacementTarget;

    }
```

Comment: Isn't your placement target also part of the same usercontrol you can directly access it using this.yourControlName, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Question have to be edited! what do you want?

Comment: If your ViewModel is looking for a placement target, you're doing it wrong.  This is all the purview of the View, not the ViewModel.  Let the View do all this work from the codebehind.

Answer (score 2):

I realise that this is an old post, but someone might find this useful to know. Assuming that you have bound your view to your view model, then you can then bind your `ContextMenu.DataContext` to your view model in the following way:

First, name your view `UserControl`... I generally name all of mine `This` for simplicity. Then remembering that our view model is bound to the `DataContext` of the `UserControl`, we can bind to the view model using `{Binding DataContext, ElementName=This}`.

So now we can bind to the view model, we have to connect that with the `ContextMenu.DataContext`. I use the `Tag` property of the object with the `ContextMenu` (the `PlacementTarget`) as that connection, in this example, a `Grid`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="YourTemplate" DataType="{x:Type DataTypes:YourDataType}">
    <Grid ContextMenu="{StaticResource Menu}" Tag="{Binding DataContext, 
        ElementName=This}">
        ...
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

We can then access the view model properties and commands in the `ContextMenu` by binding the `ContextMenu.DataContext` property to the `PlacementTarget.Tag` property (of the `Grid` in our example):

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="Menu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource=
    {RelativeSource Self}}">
    <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteFile}" CommandParameter=
        "{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
        AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" CommandTarget="{Binding PlacementTarget, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

Note the binding on the `MenuItem.CommandTarget` property. Setting this ensures that the target element on which the specified command is raised is the `PlacementTarget`, or the `Grid` in this case.

Also note the `CommandParameter` binding. This binds to the `DataContext` of the `PlacementTarget`, or the `Grid` in this case. The `DataContext` of the `Grid` will be inherited from the `DataTemplate` and so your data item is now bound to the `object` parameter in your `Command` if you're using some implementation of the `ICommand` interface:

```
public bool CanExecuteDeleteFileCommand(object parameter)
{
    return ((YourDataType)parameter).IsInvalid;
}

public void ExecuteDeleteFileCommand(object parameter)
{
    Delete((YourDataType)parameter);
}
```

Or if you are using some kind of `RelayCommand` delegates directly in your view model:

```
public ICommand Remove
{
    get 
    {
        return new ActionCommand(execute => Delete((YourDataType)execute), 
            canExecute => return ((YourDataType)canExecute).IsInvalid); 
    }
}
```