# Binding details of a TreeViewItem to a ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a ContextMenu that appears on a right click of a TreeViewItem.  What I would like to do now is pass a couple of details about the TreeViewItem to the context menu.

How would I do that starting from here:

XAML

```
<TreeView x:Class="MyApp.TreeControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" 
         PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TreeView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
         PreviewMouseMove="TreeView_PreviewMouseMove" 
         PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="TreeControl_OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown">
<TreeView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Name="dataItem1" Header="Property1"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Name="dataItem2" Header="Property2"></MenuItem>
        <Separator/>
        <MenuItem Name="taskItem" Header="Tasks" Click="TaskItem_OnClick"></MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</TreeView.ContextMenu>
</TreeView>
```

I would like the words `Property1` and `Property2` replaced by the values of those properties in the TreeViewItem that was right clicked, sort of like : `{binding selectedItem.Property1}`

Code: (basically to highlight the clicked node)

```
private void TreeControl_OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem treeViewItem = VisualUpwardSearch(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);

    if (treeViewItem != null)
    {
        treeViewItem.IsSelected = true;
        treeViewItem.Focus();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you need to do is to data bind your `MenuItem.Header` properties to an object that you set into the `ContextMenu.DataContext`:

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={
        RelativeSource Self}}">
    <MenuItem Name="dataItem1" Header="{Binding Property1}"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Name="dataItem2" Header="{Binding Property2}"></MenuItem>
    <Separator/>
    <MenuItem Name="taskItem" Header="Tasks" Click="TaskItem_OnClick"></MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

What is this `PlacementTarget.Tag`, I hear you ask. Looking at the [`ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, we see that it:

> Gets or sets the `UIElement` relative to which the `ContextMenu` is positioned when it opens.

In plain English, that just means *the UI element that has the `ContextMenu` applied to it*. Now the `Tag` property is just a free property of type `object` that we can put anything into. In your case, we're going to put the `ContextMenu.DataContext` value in there because we can't set it directly, because the `ContextMenu` is not part of the general UI visual tree:

Now you didn't show the code where you apply the `ContextMenu` to the `TreeViewItem`, but in that same place, you need to set the `Tag` property to the object that you want to set as the `ContextMenu.DataContext` value. So we pass it in here and take it out in the `ContextMenu` as shown in the code example.

For more information, please take a look at my answers from the [ContextMenu.PlacementTarget is not getting set, no idea why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739282/contextmenu-placementtarget-is-not-getting-set-no-idea-why) and [Add context menu in datagrid, how to get the select Item value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610905/add-context-menu-in-datagrid-how-to-get-the-select-item-value/18611364#18611364) questions here on Stack Overflow.