# How can I select ListView item by swipe?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I select ListView item by swipe, please?
If I swipe over ViewCell of ListView I have not data of the swiped ViewCell in SelectedItem, but I would like to have it for delete this item.
This is how it works when I tapp on ViewCell and I would like to make it work the same way with swipe.

```
<control:SwipeableListView x:Name="peopleList" ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped" SwipedLeft="Handle_SwipedLeft" Margin="10" SeparatorVisibility="None" RowHeight="70">     
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                     .
                     .
                     .
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know the listView viewCell whose contextAction menuItem is clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991411/how-to-know-the-listview-viewcell-whose-contextaction-menuitem-is-clicked)

Comment: Thanks, but it works for menuItem. How can I do it for my code? Thanks.